# Annotation to invoke REST service by Content-Type parameter

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, multipart

I have tried to google but was not able to find something on this topic.
The question is:

I have

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; TYPE=<paramValue>; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMfWZACtN4mYmJK06;
```

where **paramValue** could be **paramValue1** and **ParamValue2**

Is there anyway to defer REST calls by TYPE parameter value. Something like:

```
@Consumes("multipart/mixed; TYPE=paramValue1")
@POST
postParameterValue1()
```

and

```
@Consumes("multipart/mixed; TYPE=param**Value2**")
@POST
postParameterValue2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make clear which REST library. The ones I know cannot handle your request. How can you ever predict the boundary parameter, for example? And what is "TYPE"? Is it really part of your content-type or just a vehicle for controlling your server?
I would say, no - it's not possible with restEASY. And it seems to be quite hard to implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't need to predict **bodypart**. It's just an example. We can forget about it. About REST implementation. I am using javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar. **TYPE** is just custom parameter and could have only several values. I was able to get the map of **content-type** header parameters:

```
Map<String, String> contentTypeParameters = multiPart.getMediaType().getParameters();
```

And thought there may be an Annotation which let me avoid implementing this in programmatic meaner. If somebody faced this issue and know the answer - I'll  be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that with annotation.
I suggest you to write a small logic to handle this situation.

First you should create a rest method to receive all the requests. The input parameter of this method should  be the value of the `Content-Type` header. Then you can check the value and do anything what you want:

```
private static final String CASE_1 = "paramValue1" 

@POST
postParameterValue(@HeaderParam("Content-Type") final String contentType) {
    if (CASE_1.equals(contentType)) {
        handleCase1Request();
    } else {
        handleCase2Request();
    }

}

private void handleCase1Request() {
    // do anything what you like
}

private void handleCase2Request() {
    // do anything what you like
}
```